# Use Camera From Other Laptop as Current Machine's Webcam

Tags: google-chrome, broadcom, webcam, camera

I am new here and if this is a wrong forum to post this question then please forward me to the correct one.

I have a windows laptop (WL) and a linux laptop(LL). I am having a google meet call on chrome on LL but instead of using its own camera, I want to use the camera of WL as my video stream on that call. Both WL and LL are on different wifi and placed remotely. Can you tell me how can I do that? Any software recommendations?

Reason to use is not scamming or anything illegal but my LL’s camera is not working and I have a series of meetings to attend in coming week. I could have used epoccam and use my phone but I have to showcase apps using my same phone.

Comment: Can you do this *easily*? No. I really don't think so. I would be curious to see how deep someone would go through the rabbit hole to set something like this up. I imagine the setup would be something like like OBS-studio on the Windows device to record and broadcast from the webcam and then you'd need VLC *and* OBS *and* your video call app to stream the broadcast from the Windows laptop, OBS to *broadcast it again*... It might not be worth the time and effort

Comment: You'll probably more likely get an answer if you told us why you want/need that setup. The use cases for such a setup that immediately come to my mind are setting up a scam, cheating at an online exam or other illegitimate actions. If, however, there's a legitimate reason for that setup, please [edit] your question and tell us. Maybe there's even a much simpler solution to your original problem.

Comment: Done, written the “why” in question.

Comment: What OS/release are you using?  (for what you call LL)

Comment: WL- Win10, LL- Arch Linux